# Android: Async Task : doInBackground returns before an action callback

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using MQTT for my Android Application. I implemented the MQTT connection in a class extending the AsyncTask. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG = "MQTT";
    private Context context;
    String status;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
         context = getApplicationContext();
        MQTT mqtt = new MQTT();
        mqtt.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class MQTT extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String clientId = generateClientId();
            MqttAndroidClient client =
                    new MqttAndroidClient(context, "tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883",
                            clientId);

            try {
                IMqttToken token = client.connect();
                token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                        // We are connected
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
                        status = "True";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");
                        status = "False";


                    }
                });
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "value of status " + status);
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.d(TAG, s);


        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing here is that doInBackground() returns before the onSuccess is called. Because of this, this function returns status as null. I tried to take the Log of the returned value in the onPostExecute(), it shows null. Whereas I am assigning the value of status in the onSuccess function inside the doInBackGround. Is there a way I can make sure that the doInBackground returns only after the onSuccess is completed.

Comment: Are you sure you need an AsyncTask for this?

Comment: Return `token` in the doInBackground. Set the action callback from onPostExecute

Comment: Thanks @JyotmanSingh : I am new to Android. As per the guidelines, network related tasks are well of in the Async Task. But do you think it will be a good idea to put this in the onCreate?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 I will read about it.

Comment: Read about what? I assume `client.connect()` is the network operation you need to do, so there is no reason to set an asynchronous callback within another asynchronous call.

Comment: Yes try removing the AsyncTask. It seems MqttAndroidClient uses its own thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution is to block until async task finishes, e. g. by using `Semaphore`:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String clientId = generateClientId();
    MqttAndroidClient client = // ....                 
    Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
    try {
       IMqttToken token = client.connect();
       token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess() {
               // ...
               status = "True";
               s.release();
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure() {
               // ...
               status = "False";
               s.release();
           }
       });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         s.release();
    }
    s.acquire();   // blocks until `s.release()` is invoked in callback
    return status;
}
```